# trying to create just a solid white border at the top of the main content element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create just a solid white 10px border at the top of this main content (.tab-pane) element but no matter what I try, I keep getting this boxed outline and a white border at top with grey in the middle and white on the sides. Maybe I'm trying to do it on the wrong element (but i want it right below the nav in between the nav and the main content). 
here's some of my css:

```
.tab-pane { 
  border-top: 10px;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 100%;          
}
```

Comment: If someone's solution solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. For more info: [how does accepting an answer work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Try this short version

```
border-top: 10px solid #FFF;
```

Otherwise, the full code should be:

```
border-top-color: #FFF;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 10px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your markup the area that you want to target is the id = home so if you add a background color of white to that id in your css that gray bar will go away. so at the bottom of your stylesheet/css just add the following code.

CSS

```
#home {
   background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: thanks @David Willhite ! this actually helps me understand how this all works together alot better- thanks!